# Faster code to create an Index with Dict

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have an np array `trainY` of tuples.  Each tuple is a set of labels:

```
array([('php', 'image-processing', 'file-upload', 'upload', 'mime-types'),
       ('firefox',), 
       ('r', 'matlab', 'machine-learning'),
       ('c#', 'url', 'encoding'), 
       ('php', 'api', 'file-get-contents'),
       ('proxy', 'active-directory', 'jmeter'), 
       ('core-plot',),
       ('c#', 'asp.net', 'windows-phone-7'),
       ('.net', 'javascript', 'code-generation'),
       ('sql', 'variables', 'parameters', 'procedure', 'calls')], dtype=object)
```

I want to create an Dict object which acts as an index.  The keys will be the labels and the values will be a list containing the row numbers that each key appears in:

e.g;

key: value

'php': {[0,4]}

My current code to do this is:

```
label_index = {}
for i, labels in enumerate(trainY):
    for label in labels:
        if label in label_index.keys():
            label_index[label].append(i)
        else:
            label_index[label] = [i]
```

Is there a faster (perhaps vectorised) way to write the code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> a = np.array([('php', 'image-processing', 'file-upload', 'upload', 'mime-types'),
       ('firefox',), 
       ('r', 'matlab', 'machine-learning'),
       ('c#', 'url', 'encoding'), 
       ('php', 'api', 'file-get-contents'),
       ('proxy', 'active-directory', 'jmeter'), 
       ('core-plot',),
       ('c#', 'asp.net', 'windows-phone-7'),
       ('.net', 'javascript', 'code-generation'),
       ('sql', 'variables', 'parameters', 'procedure', 'calls')], dtype=object)

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, x in enumerate(a):
...     for k in x:
...         d[k].append(i)
...         
>>> d['php']
[0, 4]
```

Comment: Worth noting that though this makes the code nicer, it will have pretty much the same runtime as @gnibbler's answer. (But I don't see any way to make the actual operation faster other than dropping into Cython/C.)

Comment: `defaultdict` is awesome, never knew about that.  When should I use the normal `dict`? Ever?

Answer (score 2):

In Python2, `dict.keys()` returns a list, so in addition to creating an unnecessary list, it turns a O(1) lookup into a linear scan

```
label_index = {}
for i, labels in enumerate(trainY):
    for label in labels:
        if label in label_index:
            label_index[label].append(i)
        else:
            label_index[label] = [i]
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  My code didn't complete last night but with your change, it finished in < 1 min.  I marked the other response as the answer because I learned something new (i.e. `defaultdict`).